# Why refresh token gets regenerated when i try to regenerate my access token in salesforce wave analytics?

Tags: einstein-analytics, refresh-token

When i try to regenerate my expired access token, the refresh token also gets regenerated. I've set "**Refresh token is valid until revoked**" under **OAuth policies** for my app but still every time a new refresh tokens gets generated.

Are there any settings available where i can change this or is this default behavior in Salesforce wave analytics?